# Credentials Issue in Azure Container for images from dockerhub

Tags: azure, dockerhub, azure-container-instances

I attempted to host the image from docker hub to azure and for the first time the credentials supplied went well . But after a re-start of the container , it is having credentials issue . And I'm not sure where the credentials can be supplied . Any help >

[image: Error Message when re-starting Container]

Comment: could you please provide mow info /context. I don't understand where the error comes from ?  Maybe share the CLI command you used or the ARM template ?

Comment: Hi @djsly , I did not use CLI to create the container . Rather used the Azure portal to create a container and chose the option of using a public docker image which I pulled using my Docker credentials . Does this helps

Comment: How do you encounter the error ?  How to you restart it ?

Comment: The error appears each time when you restart the container in the Azure portal?

Comment: Hi @NancyXiong yes . It is not the case if the image is a public image which obviously removes the need for a credential .  As Im testing I did not want to use the space in the Azure Container Registry for time-being as it costs some dollars .

Comment: Ensure that the image exists in the registry, and that you've typed the image name correctly. Try to remove this ACI then re-deploy it via Azure portal again? Is this error still existed? Or check the [diagnostic logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-get-logs#get-diagnostic-events).

Comment: can you try issuing the restart not using the portal ? az cli maybe ? maybe the restart payload removed some credentials from the internal resource.

Comment: also, can you get the output of your container object using 
resources.azure.com
before and after the restart to see if the container fields are different.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot that you create the container instance in the portal?

Comment: Do you still work on this issue or you already solve it?

Comment: It got resolved without having to do anything special . At the moment I'm able to restart the container without any issues